# Can we get "agent status report" and "agent performance report" through historical metrics using APIs in Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, metrics, amazon-connect

I hope everyone is doing great.
I am working on Amazon Connect reporting APIs. The basic need to post this question is that I want to get agent performance and agent status report through historical metrics using APIs. I am trying to find an API that will give me agent status from midnight that is only possible through historical metrics.
I don't want to use Streams APIs. If anyone has any solution kindly respond to me, it would be very helpful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The current reporting API only provides one function for retrieving historical data, [GetMetricData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html), and that function is only able to return queue or channel statistics. Agent specific data is only available via agent event stream and console-based reports at this time. So, unfortunately, there is no way to do what your describing with an API in Amazon Connect right now.